# Help me find $P(A \cup B')$ under the given conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was assigned the task to solve this problem by mathematics teacher which I can't solve because it doesn't make sense to me (I think that it is impossible to solve it).

There was an error please try again.

### Edited Problem:

> Events $A$ and $B$ satisfy $P( (A \cap B)')=0.2,P(A)=P(B)=$   $0.5$
>    Find $P(A \cup B')$.

I think this problem can't be solved because $P(A \cup B)<P(A \cap B)$. This is kind of impossible in my opinion.I might be wrong here.

*Note: No other information is given even from the resource from which mathematics teacher took the problem.*

Comment: The notation ' (prime) is being used here to denote the complement.  So $P((A \cup B)') \equiv P(\text{not }(A \cup B))$.

Comment: I have probably made a mistake in editing. What is the probability you are looking for? Apart from that possible mistake of my editing the question, are you sure all the given assumptions are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some basic identities**

$P(A\cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$

$P(A-B) = P(A\cap B') = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$

$P(A')= 1-P(A)$

---

$P(A\cup B)= 1-P\big((A\cup B)'\big)  = 1- 0.2 = 0.8$

Then, $P(A\cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cup B) = 0.2 $

Thus, $P(A\cap B')= P(A) - P(A\cap B) = 0.5-0.2 =0.3$

---

**Second edit**

Yes, this cannot be true for the following reasons. One reason is the one you mention, since it holds (in general) that $(A\cap B) \subseteq (A\cup B) \implies P(A\cap B) \leq P(A\cup B)$.

Also, someone can notice that $(A\cap B) \subseteq A \implies \boxed{P(A\cap B) \le P(A)}$.

After some calculations, we have
$P(A\cap B)= 1- P\big[(A\cap B)'\big] = 0.8 \color{red}{\ge } P(A)= 0.5$,  which is a contradiction.

Comment: I know them but this question just doesn't make sense. I even know the answer (teacher told me but couldn't explain why) but how to solve it is the question.

Comment: I had a typo in the problem.Please try again.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for providing second reason as well to mine. The problem is wrong.

Comment: @DevarshRuparelia You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, the prime ($'$) is being used to denote the complement of the set—in this case, $(A \cup B)'$ means not $(A \cup B)$.

To provide some intuition behind thanasissdr's answer: Consider that $P(A) = P(B) = 1/2$.  In some sense, both $A$ and $B$ cover half of the probability space.  But we are told $P((A \cup B)') \equiv P(\text{not }(A \cup B)) = 1/5$, meaning that $1/5$ of the probability space is uncovered.  $A$ and $B$ must therefore overlap by $1/5$, leaving $1/5$ to be covered by neither.

That means that $A \cap B$ covers $1/5$, while $B \cap \text{not }A$ and $A \cap \text{not }B$ both cover $1/2 - 1/5 = 3/10$.  The last of these is the quantity you want.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. But the question is something different. I edited the problem. It had a typo before.